# Angular Application Doesn't load up App Module/Components after Upgrade to Angular 8.3.5

Tags: angular, webpack, angular8, webpack-style-loader, angular-upgrade

We have an `Angular 4` project that I've recently tried to upgrade to `Angular 8`. I followed the migration guide in Angular website, changed some of the syntaxes, and everything preventing project to be built. I faced the problem of my styles were not loading properly locally and not at all on Azure. 
I found `Webpack` and tried to configure it, added style-loader, sass-loader, and css-loader. 
Now when I'm running locally, I can see in the network tab in the browser that all styles are loading properly, but it only loads the default index.html file and not bootstrapping the application.

When I deploy the app on Azure, it loads other components, but none of the styles are loading. I spent 3 weeks on migration, nothing promising yet.

**Tools/Plugins version:**

```js
Angular CLI: 8.3.5
Node: 10.15.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.5
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.5
@angular/cdk                      8.2.0
@angular/cli                      8.3.5
@angular/http                     5.2.11
@angular/material                 8.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.5
@schematics/angular               8.3.5
@schematics/update                0.803.5
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.40.2
```

**Here is my Webpack config:**

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const CircularDependencyPlugin = require('circular-dependency-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const { IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/index-html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'eval',

  entry: {
    main: './src/main.ts',
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
    styles: './src/styles.scss'
  },

  output: {
    path: resolve('./dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: rxPaths()
  },

  node: false,

  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: '@ngtools/webpack'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(ngfactory|ngstyle).js$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: 'source-map-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ['sass-loader'],
        // use: ['to-string-loader, css-loader, sass-loader'],
        exclude: [resolve('./src/styles.scss')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        // use: ['sass-loader'],
        include: [resolve('./src/styles.scss')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|cur)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: `[name].[ext]`,
          limit: 10000
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          name: `[name].[ext]`,
          limit: 10000
        }
      },

      // This hides some deprecation warnings that Webpack throws

      {
        test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new IndexHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      input: 'index.html',
      output: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      entrypoints: [
        'styles',
        'polyfills',
        'main'
      ]
    }),

    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      mainPath: resolve('./src/main.ts'),
      sourceMap: true,
      nameLazyFiles: true,
      tsConfigPath: resolve('./src/tsconfig.app.json')
      // ,
      // skipCodeGeneration: true
    }),

    new ProgressPlugin(),

    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
      exclude: /[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]/
    }),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'src/assets',
        to: 'assets'
      },
      {
        from: 'src/favicon.ico'
      }
    ])
  ]
};
```

Please note that the reason I've commented use[] in Webpack config was that it was throwing some postcss-loader exception and on an issue on Github found that some conflict will occur with default sass-loader and Webpack and you should remove them.

**Here is the build config in angular.json**

```js
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            },
            "outputPath": "./dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/config",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/metismenu/dist/metisMenu.js",
              "node_modules/vis/dist/vis.min.js",
              "vendor/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.min.js",
              "vendor/js/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-us-mill.js",
              "vendor/js/iCheck/icheck.js",
              "node_modules/toastr/toastr.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "local": {
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "styles": [
                "./src/styles.scss"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

**And here is the serve config in Angular.json.**

```js
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "projectName:build",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local":{
              "browserTarget": "projectName:build:local"
            }
            ,
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "projectName:build:dev"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "projectName:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

I have imported all styles in styles.scss using @import statements.
Just one thing I am not sure about is that I'm using Highcharts and getting some warnings during the build.

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/angular2-highcharts/dist/index.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) Cannot find source file '../src/index.ts': Error: Can't resolve '../src/index.ts'
```

Other than these, there is not compile/runtime error in the project.

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem. I appreciate any hint/tip.

***Update:***
This is how the project structure looks like:

```js
|   .editorconfig
|   .gitignore
|   angular.json
|   browserslist
|   karma.conf.js
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   protractor.conf.js
|   README.md
|   tsconfig.json
|   tslint.json
|   webpack.config.js
|          
+---src
|   |   favicon.ico
|   |   index.html
|   |   index.js
|   |   main.ts
|   |   polyfills.ts
|   |   styles.scss
|   |   test.ts
|   |   tsconfig.app.json
|   |   tsconfig.spec.json
|   |   typings.d.ts
|   |   webpack.config.common.js
|   |   
|   +---app       
|   +---assets
|   |   |
|   |   +---images
|   |   \---styles
|   |       |   style.scss
|   |       |   
|   |               
|   +---config
|   |       dev-config.js
|   |       local-config.js
|   |       prod-config.js
|   |       qa-config.js
|   |       
|   +---environments
|   |       environment.dev.ts
|   |       environment.prod.ts
|   |       environment.qa.ts
|   |       environment.ts
```

Comment: I had the same problem a few days ago. And i am still searching for it.

Comment: Please post your project structure.

Comment: @PhatHuynh added project structure.

Comment: Looking forward to see the solution

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi Don't you think you missed anything here "changed some of the syntaxes"?

Comment: I solved this kind of issue (upgrade angular 4 to angular 7) before

Comment: @NaserNikzad what is it?

Comment: Nothing specific, I just meant, make sure you are not missing any step, so it is usually helpful to review your configs.

Answer (score 3):

The file index.ts is missing from the project it seems that the file index.js extension was changed from ts to js and it is looking for it as ts.

Try with changing the index.js extension with index.ts in the src folder.

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi why do you use `index.js` file? what is for? index.html is used to be as placeholder for the application, however, there is no need for code. Could you show the content of `index.js` file?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the main problem is that styles are not applied.

You are using Bootstrap files according to this row of your config: `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"`, however you have not imported this styles into final bundle. So try to write this into `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
],
```

In addition, you need to import  `bootstrap` styles to use them in your application into `style.scss` file:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

<!-- 
     h1, h2, h3 {
         margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
     } 
-->
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Our `app.module.ts` should look like this after creating through Angular CLI:

   ```
   @NgModule({
       declarations: [
       AppComponent
       ],
       imports: [
           BrowserModule,
           AppRoutingModule
       ],
       providers: [],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule { }
   ```

Every application should have a start place. In Angular, we have a convention, that our application should start at `AppModule`. `AppModule` is our rout module. So we are telling to Angular that when it creates our root module(`AppModule`) at start that we want to set `AppComponent` as a starting point(`bootstrap`) into the DOM.

The code that will bootstrap your application placed into `main.ts` file:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The above code uses Just in Time compilation.

Let me show how `index.html` looks:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Frontend</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `<app-root></app-root>` is a selector for `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Frontend';
  test = {};
}
```

You can change the default page to show by replacing  by the selector of your component in the `index.html`.

**Double check your selector of  `app.component.html` and selector used in in your  `index.html`.**

2. Try to set projectName to your name of project in the `serve` section of `angular.json` file. For example, if your project is named as `superappl`, then you should write like this:

   ```
   serve": {
     "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
     "options": {
       "browserTarget": "superappl:build",
       "customWebpackConfig": {
         "path": "./webpack.config.js"
       }
     },
     "configurations": {
       "local":{
         "browserTarget": "superappl:build:local"
       }
       ,
       "dev": {
         "browserTarget": "superappl:build:dev"
       },
       "production": {
         "browserTarget": "superappl:build:production"
       }
     }
   },
   ```
3. If above actions will not run your application. Then I suggest you to create new brand application using `Angular CLI` and compare your `index.html` file and `app.module.ts` files. Commands to create new brand application to compare your existing application (especially, `package.json` and `angular.json` files):

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ng new angular-newapp --skip-install
   npm install @angular/core@latest
   npm install @angular/http@latest
   npm install
   ng serve
   ```

Some questions:

1. Have you created manually `Webpack.config`? What's reason to use it? You can avoid using and tuning `Webpack config` if it is applicable to you. As Angular CLI by default does not create this file. You should manually write `ng-eject` command to get webpack file.
2. Can you post your `index.html` and `app.module.ts`?
3. Does your application work when you run your application locally? I mean when you run command `ng serve`?

Comment: Styles are loading correctly now, (As I see in network tab). Current problem is that when I run application, it only loads default index.html file. Doesn't boot up AppModule. To be specific, it should redirect to login page or dashboard, but it doesn't. When I enter localhost/login in browser, the document loads in network tab, but component doesn't load. Just stuck in default index.html

Comment: On Azure, true, styles are not loading. About bootstrap, I've imported into styles.scss file as angular doc suggests.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer question. I'll definitely try all of them. But most of them are already checked. I'm busy this week, will post an update ASAP.

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi you are welcome! I believe that it will help to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this kind of issue before like this:

STEP 1: Remove `node_modules`

STEP 2: `npm i`

STEP 3(if it doesn't work): `npm rebuild node-sass`

On my case it worked fine.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck